# Construction a Bernstein set that is an additive group

Tags: general-topology, set-theory, descriptive-set-theory, forcing

I would like to start by showing that there exists a Bernstein set $B$ that is additive group. To see that, it is an easy transfinite induction to construct  a Bernstein set that is a linear independent over $\mathbb Q$, say $B_1$. Let $B$ be a linear space that generated by $B_1.$

Claim , The the set $B$ is as needed. Indeed, $B$ intersects each  perfect set since $B_1$ does so. It remains to show $B$ does not contain any perfect set, Consdier the quotient space $\mathbb R\setminus B$, for contradiction, assume $P\subset B$ where $P$ is a perfect set. Then, any nonzero cost $x+B$ where $x\notin B$ would conatin $x+P$ and $x+P$ is perfect set disjoint with $B.$ This proves the claim.

Now, assume we have a meager set $M\subset R$ with cardinality  $\mathfrak c.$ My question, I want to construct a Bernstein set $B$ that is an additive group sucht $R\setminus (B\cdot M)$ has condinality $\mathfrak c$, where $B\cdot M=\{bm\colon b\in B \ \& \ m\in M\}.$

I do not know how I can start. I got a hint that said  this can be done  by using Martian axioms. I have a little knowledge about Martin axioms, actually, I know the standard applications of  Martin axioms.

Any help will be appreciated greatly.an

Comment: @Andreas Blass, Do you have an idea if it is possible or not ?

Comment: @Dave. L. Renfro, Do you have an idea if it is possible or not ?

Comment: @Brian M. Scott, Do you have an idea if it is possible or not ?
,